# How to avoid circular dependency in angular project with Apollo client and `graphql-codegen` when importing types in client resolver?

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql

My objective is to use generated types when writing client-side resolvers with the Apollo client.

Everything in the client-side resolvers is working as described by [Apollo here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/local-state/). However, in the project, we are also using generated types and GQL services as described in [this blog](https://medium.com/the-guild/apollo-angular-code-generation-7903da1f8559). And here comes the issue. If I import a type from the generated types in the client-side resolvers, I get the error:

```
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
eddy.module.ts ->
  ...graphql.module.ts ->
  ...resolvers.ts ->
  ...client-specific-recommendation-resolver.ts ->
  ...get-top-right-corner-state.ts ->
  ...graphql.ts -> // (generated types)
  ...eddy.module.ts
```

So **essentially** in the `get-top-right-corner-state.ts` file, because I import from the generated types like this:

```js
import { Something } from '../../../../../generated/graphql';
```

**Notes**

Our application loads apollo in a module called `graphql.module`, used by a feature module called "eddy". We have configured this with the `ngModule` property in the `codegen.yml` file.

What can I do to prevent this? I would very much like to utilize the types generated by `graphql-codegen`, also in my client-side resolvers.

Comment: I would first narrow down the issue that is being referenced in a circular manner. The only options you have is to re-think your design (why you are importing circular references) or, use interfaces where appropriate.

Comment: I don't know if I can change the auto-generated file that `graphql-codegen` generates, but even if I just import an interface or enum, I get a circular dependency.

Comment: I'd open up a bug with whoever owns graphql-codegen. Sounds like the issue is on their side, not yours.

Comment: Ok thanks, I Will give it a try.

Comment: The good news is that it's not a blocker for you. Obviously something that needs to be fixed, but they are just warnings.

Answer (score 1):

After reading and experimenting with this issue, I found a solution. The setup is actually pretty simple, but a tiny bit more complicated than just providing the generated services in the root of Angular.

The feature module does the Apollo setup and creates the client-side resolvers. But instead of providing the generated services here, they are provided in another module, here called lazy-loaded.module.ts. The codegen.yml now looks like this, and there are no circular dependencies:

```
generates:
 <path-to-feature-module>/graphql.ts:
   schema: <path-to-client-schema>.ts
   documents: ./src/**/*.graphql
   config:
    ngModule: <path-to-lazy-loaded-module>#LazyLoadedModule
```

The lazy loaded module is then imported by the feature module providing Apollo, and voila, problem solved